# How to determine if object is in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript array that looks like this:

```
myFields = [
["fb-method","drop",false,"How did you order?"],
["fb-date","calendar",false,""],
["fb-time","drop",false,""],
["fb-location","drop",false,""],
["fb-amount","text default",false,""],
["fb-share","drop",false,""],
["fb-msg","textarea",true,""],
["next-btn","button",true,""]
]
```

I'm able to loop through the array and deal with specific bits like this:

```
len = fields.length;

//first check to make sure required fields are filled in
for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
     a = fields[i];
     if(a[0] != "fb-method") {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I need to be able to (outside the loop) do something if a specific element isn't part of the array, specifically one that looks like this:

```
["fb-location","drop",false,""]
```

I've tried using jQuery's `.inArray` function, but it returns true even when it should return false. See [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/azWLC/).

What's the best way to go about this? jQuery or standard js is fine.

Comment: If you had read the [jQuery.inArray() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/#entry-longdesc) before using it, you would have noticed that _Because JavaScript treats 0 as loosely equal to false (i.e. 0 == false, but 0 !== false), if we're checking for the presence of value within array, we need to check if it's not equal to (or greater than) -1._

Comment: I think you have to provide a better explanation. It's not clear to me which value you want to compare against `myFields`. In the fiddle you used `"fb-location"` and in the question you mentioned `["fb-location","drop",false,""]`. `myFields` is an array of arrays. Which value do you want to compare against which array?

Comment: Yes, I know that myFields is an array of arrays. I need to know, true or false, if any of the arrays contain the value "fb-location" in any position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$.inArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) does not return a bool, it returns the index (if no match exists, it returns `-1`).  You would want this statement (based on your jsfiddle):

```
if(jQuery.inArray("fb-location", tmp) > -1) {
    alert("it exists");
}
else {
    alert("it doesn't exist");
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/azWLC/2/

***UPDATE:***

As mentioned in the comments, this is only a half solution since the array is multidimensional.  I recommend first using [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var tmp = [
["fb-method","drop",false,"How did you order?"],
["fb-date","calendar",false,""],
["fb-time","drop",false,""],
["fb-amount","text default",false,""],
["fb-share","drop",false,""],
["fb-msg","textarea",true,""],
["next-btn","button",true,""]
];
var values = $.map(tmp, function(n, i){
    return n[0];
});

if(jQuery.inArray("fb-location", values) > -1) {
    alert("it exists");
}
else {
    alert("it doesn't exist");
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/azWLC/4/

Comment: Beat me to it... +1 Also, here's a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/azWLC/1/

Comment: I think `.inArray` will only work if OP has a reference to an element of the array, not just an array with the same content.

Comment: Just to clarify, `-1` is truthy in Javascript.

Comment: Note that this is only a partial solution. The array is multidimensional. http://jsfiddle.net/azWLC/3/

Answer (score 0):

jquery.inArray returns the index of the element. If it is not found it returns -1.. And any number except 0 is true and hence it says 'it exists'

Comment: 0 is true in this case as well, it means that index 0 contained the match.

Comment: Yes. But for an `if` statement, 0 is always false

Answer (score 0):

Besides `$.inArray` you could use `Array.filter` on `tmp` this way:

```
if(  tmp.filter(function(a) {return -~a.indexOf('fb-location');}).length ) {
  // exists
}
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/4J5KF/)

See also: [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Using JQuery, you'd use the JQuery `grep` method

```
if(  $.grep(tmp,function(a) {return -~a.indexOf('fb-location');}).length ) {
  // exists
}
```